# How to make a new line when content is too long?

Tags: html, css

```css
img {
  width:20%;
}

.shopInfoL2 {
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:top;
}

h4 {
  color:red;
  }
```

```html
<h4>Div 1</h4>
<div>
  <img src="https://s.yimg.com/xd/api/res/1.2/2A8.GbmWTAlpFOqZFY.Leg--/YXBwaWQ9eXR3YXVjdGlvbnNlcnZpY2U7aD00MDA7cT04NTtyb3RhdGU9YXV0bzt3PTQwMA--/http://nevec-img.zenfs.com/prod/tw_ec05-7/71eb3ae4-2784-4a9c-a3fa-6985fd12a43f.jpg" alt="" class="imgQRL2"> 
  <div class="shopInfoL2">
    <h5>Title here</h5>
    <p>address address  </p>
  </div>
</div>
                         
                         
<h4>Div 2</h4>                         
<div>
  <img src="https://s.yimg.com/xd/api/res/1.2/2A8.GbmWTAlpFOqZFY.Leg--/YXBwaWQ9eXR3YXVjdGlvbnNlcnZpY2U7aD00MDA7cT04NTtyb3RhdGU9YXV0bzt3PTQwMA--/http://nevec-img.zenfs.com/prod/tw_ec05-7/71eb3ae4-2784-4a9c-a3fa-6985fd12a43f.jpg" alt="" class="imgQRL2"> 
  <div class="shopInfoL2">
    <h5>Title here</h5>
    <p>address address address address address address address address address address address address address address  </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here are two divs and only difference is the content length of p tag.

As you can see from result, the p length in Div2 is too long and Div2 move down to Div1.

What can I do to keep Div2 always next to Div1 and also the p tag will switch to newline when content is too long?

Comment: Set a fixed width of the `.shopInfoL2`

Answer (score 1):

Set a width to you're div `.shopInfoL2`